# Added HDD disappears from /dev

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

I had a powercut the other day, right while I was in the middle of a script that was writing a lot of data over the network to my server hdd.  On rebooting the machine I could no longer see the drive (it wasn't the boot drive).  I have take the drive out and am trying to see if i can recover the data from it using a usb hdd reader.

When I plug it in, it makes all the right noises and when its finished spinning up i run `ls /dev/sd*`
and get

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdc  /dev/sdc1
```

This disk is sdc1 - so I try to mount: `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb/` but i get `mount: special device /dev/sdc1 does not exist` - when i try `sudo fdisk -l` i get the following:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   312581807   156290903+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e5fc7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907028991  1953513472   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/proteus--vg-root: 155.5 GB, 155508015104 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 18906 cylinders, total 303726592 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/proteus--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/proteus--vg-swap_1: 3686 MB, 3686793216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 448 cylinders, total 7200768 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/proteus--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

i.e. sda/b fine but no sign of sdc
and when i try `ls /dev/sd*`

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdb1
```

sdc has gone

Any ideas of how i could possibly retrieve the data of that disk, i'm not concerned about saving the disk but really need to retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like scalpel or testdisk. They programs comb though your drive and look for file signatures like JPEG or PDF. So if your data has a specific signature, this may help. There are many more data recovery tools on Windows that can help http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have Windows

Comment: apologies, i just noticed that 2 of your recommendations are linux - i tried testdisk, If i am quick i can get it to 'recognise' there is a disk there but it cannot find any partition tables, i/o errors at 100%